# Prove that if $\langle x,x \rangle_1$ = $\langle x,x \rangle_2$ then $\langle x,y \rangle_1$ = $\langle x,y \rangle_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If for every $v\in V$  $\langle v,v\rangle_{1} = \langle v,v \rangle_{2}$ then $\langle\cdot,\cdot \rangle_{1} = \langle\cdot,\cdot \rangle_{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37252/if-for-every-v-in-v-langle-v-v-rangle-1-langle-v-v-rangle-2-then)

Let V be a real vector space, and let $\langle x,y \rangle_1$ and $\langle x,y \rangle_2$ be two inner products defined on V.

How would you prove that if $\langle x,x \rangle_1$ = $\langle x,x \rangle_2$ $\forall x\in V$ then $\langle x,y \rangle_1$ = $\langle x,y \rangle_2$ $\forall x,y\in V$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think one can use polarization identity. Since given statement implies that ${||x||}_1={||x||}_2$ for all x in V. And by polarization identity we have ${\langle{x,y}\rangle}_1$ = $\frac{1}{4}{||x+y||}^{2}_{1}$- $\frac{1}{4}{||x-y||}^{2}_{1}$ = $\frac{1}{4}{||x+y||}^{2}_{2}$- $\frac{1}{4}{||x-y||}^{2}_{2}$ = ${\langle{x,y}\rangle}_2$ for all x, y in V.

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks so much!